# How to display Pagination and Search in JQUERY Datatables having images in the table data?

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables-1.10

This is my table body.....

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body">
            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Category ID</th>
                  <th>Category Image</th>
                  <th>Category Name</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
                $res_data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_data)) {
                  // code...

                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Category_ID']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "<img src=\"data:image;base64," . $row['Category_Image_Temp'] . "\" alt=" . $row['Category_Image_Name'] . " width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\">"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Category_Name']; ?></td>
                    <td><textarea><?php echo $row['Category_Name']; ?></textarea></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">
                        </i>
                        Update
                      </a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash">
                        </i>
                        Delete
                      </a></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php

                }
                ?>



              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Category ID</th>
                  <th>Category Image</th>
                  <th>Category Name</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </section>
```

So when I remove `<td><?php echo "<img src=\"data:image;base64," . $row['Category_Image_Temp'] . "\" alt=" . $row['Category_Image_Name'] . " width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\">"; ?></td>` this line from the code, then only the pagination and search appears.

Main issue is when I display images in the datatables the pagination and search doesn't appears.

I want to display pagination and search when I display images in datatables.

Anybody can help?
Thanks....

Comment: Please see that you must match the th and td count. you have 5 table headers and 6 columns in body. that's why when you remove the image it will work fine with search and pagination but when you add image it will not.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Yes I was a silly mistake though, It worked Thanks...